# for loop only fires up once when trying to change image with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to replace an image using for loop. The main div has 7 images where only one image is visible, due to the height of the div, I'm also using overflow auto. The for loop works once and change the image. The image with id 1 disappears and next one, id 2, appears as I move the mouse to the right. The loop will work only once and it won't work again. I have even printed the pageX pageY to see if it works, but that freezes. I know the problem is with when I try append() the new image. Please see code below.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "xml/pdf_xml.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {          
        var items = parseXml_img(xml);
        load_img(items);
        img_scroller(items);
    }
});

function parseXml_img(xml) {
    var items = [];
    $(xml).find("Image").each(function(idx, v) {

        items.push({
            title: $(this).find("Title").text(), 
            date: $(this).find("Date").text(),
            id: $(this).find("id").text(),
        });
    });
    return items;}

function load_img(items) {
    var id =1;
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        items[i].id= id++;
        var galleryImage = "<div id=\"currDiv-"+items[i].id+"\"><img src=\"img/"+items[i].title+"\" id=\"curr-"+items[i].id+"\" class=\"currId\"/></div>";
        $('#main-image').append(galleryImage);
        //$('#main-image').children().not("[id='curr-1']").hide();
    }
}

function img_scroller(items) {
    var newId;
    var xPrev = 0;
    var currentId;
    var idLength = items.length;
    $('.currId').mousemove(function(e) {
        var newId; var xPrev = 0; var currentId;
        var idLength = items.length;
        var str =$(this).attr('id');
        var ret = str.split("-");
        var str1 = ret[0];
        var str2 = ret[1];
        currentId = str2;
        var newImg ="";
        if(xPrev<e.pageX) { 
            newId=0;
            $('#test').html('right,'+e.pageX+','+e.pageY);
            //currentId++;
            newId = currentId;

            if(newId >= idLength){
                newId=idLength;
            }
            //var leftId = newId;
            // var rightId = newId;
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
            var j = newId;

            $('#main-image').children().html("");
            for (j; j < items.length; j++) {
                newImg = "<img  src=\"img/"+items[j].title+"\" id=\"curr-"+items[j].id+"\" class=\"currId\"/>"; 
                $('#currDiv-'+items[j].id).html(newImg);
            }
        } else if(xPrev>e.pageX)
        {
            $('#test').html('left,'+e.pageX+','+e.pageY);
        } 
        xPrev=e.pageX;
    });
}
```

**I've made a change at the img_scroller, please below**

```
if(xPrev<e.pageX) { newId=0; newId = currentId; if(newId >= idLength){ newId=idLength; } var j = newId+1; items=[]; var testt=''; for (j; j < items.length; j++) { testt=items[j].id; $("img[id='"+items[j].id+"']").show(); $('#test').html(testt); } return testt; $('#test').html(testt); }
```

**What I've changed shown above:**

I've created a few divs to go below the images, so I could always get the scrollbar. I'm trying to show and hide the images as they go on the loop. But it seems that the loop is not reading the items array.

Comment: You should be using `callbacks`, since you're working with A(ssynchronous)jax.

Comment: He is using a callback. He calls `load_img` from the AJAX success function.

Comment: @Unai Which for loop are you talking about? The one in `load_img` or the one in `img_scroller`?

Comment: @Barmar but he's calling two functions inside. They're probably running "together" and messing things up.

Comment: @cr0ss That can't happen, since Javascript is single-threaded. Everything in the callback runs sequentially.

Comment: A possible problem is that every time you call this AJAX routine, you'll add another `mousemove` handler to all the `.currid` elements. So if this AJAX runs multiple times, you'll end up with multiple handlers, and they'll probably interfere with each other.

Comment: Thanks for comments!! The for loop causing problem is the one on the img_scroller. If I remove  $('#main-image').children().html(""); and  $('#currDiv-'+items[j].id).html(newImg); the offset works fine. I think the problem is because the main div being empty for a second the .currId gets lost, hence the loop not working again. But, I don't know how to fix it

Comment: What do you think about the .currId getting lost I've mentioned above @Barmar?

Comment: I suspect it's this issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Comment: It's not that @Barmar, I've made a change on the img_scroller and still no joy.                                                                                                                                                                                          if(xPrev<e.pageX) { 
   newId=0; 
     newId = currentId;
           if(newId >= idLength){
   newId=idLength;
  }
  var j = newId+1;
  items=[];
 var testt='';
 for (j; j < items.length; j++) {
  testt=items[j].id;    
    $("img[id='"+items[j].id+"']").show();
    $('#test').html(testt);
}
return testt;
$('#test').html(testt);
 
 }

Comment: I can't tell what you're writing. Add it at the end of the question so it's properly formatted.